# Java word finder program does not catch all unique entries in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am making a simple program to find all the words in a given string and put all the unique words into an array list. (Pretty much what `list.sort()` in python does for a list).

In my given test input however the program skips a word. Would be very thankful to get insights on why it's not catching all the words.

Here's my code :

```
public class wordFinder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is another test This is not a test";
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);
    while(match.find()) {
        wordList.add(match.group());
    }
    System.out.println(wordList);
    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++){
        for(int q = i; q< wordList.size(); q++){
            if(wordList.get(i).equals(wordList.get(q))){
                wordList.remove(q);
            }
            else continue;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(wordList);
}
```

}

P.S. I know regex and pattern/matcher is not really needed as I can just split the string. I'm doing this as I'm thinking of expanding my program later on to search for more than one specific thing.

Comment: what exactly are you using this for?

Comment: By the way, I see that all words are found!

Comment: Just a simple exercise program, i dont understand what the issue on my side is, without modifications to the code the output for the given input skips 'another'.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use a `Set` (**A collection that contains no duplicate elements**).  Thats what its designed for.  Your method for removing duplicates is flawed.  Step through it in a debugger and you will see when you remove the word 'another' (hint: when `i = q`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is another test This is not a test";
    Set<String> wordList = new HashSet<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);
    while(match.find()) {
        wordList.add(match.group());
    }
    System.out.println(wordList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an option is better than adding then removing. Also, like I said what would you be using this for? If you are using it for a word bank you may want to consider other structures!

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String input = "This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is another test This is not a test";
        String [] tokens = input.split("\\s");
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i){
            if(!list.contains(tokens[i])){
                list.add(tokens[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "This is a test This is a test test test This test This is a test This is a test This is another test This is not a test";
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);

        while(match.find()) {
            if (wordList.size() == 0 || wordList.indexOf(match.group()) == -1){
                wordList.add(match.group());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(wordList);
    }
```

Output:
[This, is, a, test, another, not]